# Promotion code for multiple products

Tags: promotions

I need a way to create a promotion code linked to a group of products. What I mean is:
Promotion code 1 will add item1, item2 and item3 to the shopping cart for free
Promotion code 2 will add item1, item4 and item5 to the shopping cart for free
etc

My understanding is that this is not possible using the built-in promotion code feature.

**QUESTION:** Is there a plugin out there to do this?

thanks